# Loop through a List to check whether a bool is true within a ScriptableObject

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a character Scriptable Object 'Character' and it has a bool IsMale. I also have a 'Team' Scriptable Object and it has a list of Characters from the Character Scriptable Object Class. Now, I want to create a custom method in the Team Class for looping through this list and check how many characters are male and how many are not.

Character.cs

```
 using UnityEngine;

 // Personal Attributes
 public string firstName;
 public string middleName;
 public string lastName;
 public string fullName;

 public bool isMale;
```

Team.cs

```
 using UnityEngine;

 public List<Character> characters;

 // For adding ten players.
 public void AddPlayer(Character p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10)
 {
 characters.Add(p1);
 characters.Add(p2);
 characters.Add(p3);
 characters.Add(p4);
 characters.Add(p5);
 characters.Add(p6);
 characters.Add(p7);
 characters.Add(p8);
 characters.Add(p9);
 characters.Add(p10);
 }
 // I want to loop through these ten characters in the list and tell how many are males and how many are not
```

Again, I want to create a custom method in the Team Class for looping through this list and check how many characters are male and how many are not.

For the questions in the comments @derHugo
Character.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[CreateAssetMenu()]
public class Character : ScriptableObject
{
    // Personal Attributes
    public string firstName;
    public string middleName;
    public string lastName;
    public string fullName;

    public bool isMale;

    private int age;
    public int personalMoney;

    public Sprite image;

    // Game Attributes
    public int totalRuns;
    public int salary;

    public enum characterTypes { PlayerCharacter, Manager, Player, Staff };
    public characterTypes characterType;
    public enum battingHands { LeftHanded, RightHanded };
    public battingHands battingHand;
    public enum bowlingHands { LeftHanded, RightHanded };
    public bowlingHands bowlingHand;
    public enum battingMentalities { Aggressive, Balanced, Defensive };
    public battingMentalities battingMentality;
    public enum bowlingMentalities { Aggressive, Balanced, Defensive };
    public bowlingMentalities bowlingMentality;

    // Skills
    // Technical Skills
    public int technical; // Overall Technical
    public int judgement; // Batting
    public int agility; // Running, Low means if player accidentaly falls down, the time he will take to get back up
    public int cardioFitness; // Injury
    public int muscleFitness; // Injury and Hitting Power
    public int runSpeed; // Running
    public int strength; // Hitting Power

    // Methods
    // Personal Attributes Methods
    public void CalculateAge(DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        age = 0;
        age = DateTime.Now.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
        if (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < dateOfBirth.DayOfYear)
            age = age - 1;
    }

    // Starting Game Methods Required
    public void SetCharacterType(characterTypes cT)
    {
        Debug.Log("Setting Character Type for " + fullName);

        cT = characterType;

        if (cT == characterTypes.PlayerCharacter)
        {
            Debug.Log(fullName + " is a Player Character");
        }
        else if (cT == characterTypes.Manager)
        {
            Debug.Log(fullName + " is a Manager");
        }
        else if (cT == characterTypes.Player)
        {
            Debug.Log(fullName + " is a Player");
        }
        else if (cT == characterTypes.Staff)
        {
            Debug.Log(fullName + " is a Staff");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No Character Type");
        }
    }
    public void TechnicalAverage()
    {
        technical = (judgement + agility + cardioFitness + muscleFitness + runSpeed + strength / 600) * 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i were you i would change the `AddPlayer(Character p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10)` to `AddPlayer(Character p)`. Then add them differently and also keep a counter for males/females and check every time i add a character and increase the counter for male of female. Then you don't have to loop the list every time you need this information.

Comment: @AliKanat maybe he wants to be sure it is always called with exactly 10 characters

Comment: @derHugo Yes actually that makes sense. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I am making a cricket game. That is why I have added 10 players (I know that there's 11 players but this is just for testing purposes). I want to make sure that the players are added. A must. I am also 15 and also a beginner in Unity. That might also be the reason for such amateurishness.

Comment: alternatively you could use a `Character[] characters = new Character[10];` since you don't want the size to be dynamic

Comment: I am not to comfortable with arrays than I am with lists. So????

Comment: @SwastikBhattacharyya I'm saying you could .. you don't have to. Just: List is dynamic so everytime you call `Add` it internally allocates new memory for an array in incremental steps (probably not noticable at this size). At beginning the capacity is `0` -> `Add` => capacity `4` -> once exeeding 4 it expands the array with double size `8` than `16` etc. So by using it for 10 or 11 elements you actually allocate memory for `16` elements allways ...

Comment: Hmmm. I think that I need to change my formula a bit @derHugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. use [Linq Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count) for that (I'ld rather use properties here but you could do the same using methods ofcourse.):

```
using System.Linq;

public int Males
{
    get
    {
        return characters != null ? characters.Count(c => c.isMale) : 0;
    }
}

public int Females
{
    get
    {
        return characters != null ? characters.Count(c => !c.isMale) : 0;
    }
}
```

---

You would simply use that value like e.g.

```
Debug.LogFormat(this, "Males: {0}, Females: {1}", Males, Females);
```

---

**Hint**: even though the Unity Inspector automatically initializes `List` and array fields you shoudl always do it together with the definition like

```
public List<Character> characters = new List<Character>(10);
```

just to be sure it is never `null` when calling `Add` and make sure to set a default capacity to what you expect the List to have as Count later.

Or alternatively you could use

```
Character[] characters = new Character[10];
```

since you don't want the size to be dynamic anyway. (**Note** however that the Inspector in Unity always overrides those definitions)

The reason why this is better: `List` in the background stores it's values in an array anyway. By adding elements using `Add` it everytime checks if the array is still big enough and if not expands it to the double size (see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OoRIHl))

```
public void AddPlayer(Character p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10)
{
    characters.Add(p1); // characters has now capacity 4
    characters.Add(p2);
    characters.Add(p3);
    characters.Add(p4);
    characters.Add(p5); // characters reallocated and has now capacity 8 
    characters.Add(p6);
    characters.Add(p7);
    characters.Add(p8);
    characters.Add(p9); // characters reallocated and has now capacity 16
    characters.Add(p10);
}
```

so you see using `Add` 10 or 11 times always allocates more memory than actually needed.

I would do

```
// hide because if you do it via the method you probably don't
// want to add items via Inspector which would get overwritten later anyway
[HideInInspector] public Character[] characters = new Character[10];

public void AddPlayer(Character p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10)
{
    characters[0] = p1;
    characters[1] = p2;
    characters[2] = p3;
    characters[3] = p4;
    characters[4] = p5;
    characters[5] = p6;
    characters[6] = p7;
    characters[7] = p8;
    characters[8] = p9;
    characters[9] = p10;
}
```

other than that there is no big difference between how you access or change values in array or List.

---

For setting all the values you need for every character you could/should use a proper constructor (I would change the naming though):

```
[Serializable]
public class Character
{
    // Personal Attributes
    public string firstName;
    public string middleName;
    public string lastName;
    public string fullName;

    public bool isMale;

    public Character(string _firstName, string _middleName, string _lastName, bool _isMale)
    {
        firstName = _firstName;
        middleName = _middleName;
        lastName = _lastName;

        fullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, middleName, lastName);

        isMale = _isMale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the `public List<Character> characters = new List<Character>();
` code. Now I can easily use the inspector to add all the players in the List. Makes life so easier ;).

Comment: but be aware than that the Inspector is not bound to array or List size limits ;) And it will only work if `Character` is makred as `[Serializable]`

Comment: Uhh. Unity never gets old.

Comment: Anyway. I don't think that any cricket team in the history had 1,00,000 players. So, I can definitely make past the size limits ;).

Comment: @SwastikBhattacharyya yeah it's just tiny details ;) that's why I put it only as `Hint`.

Comment: Anyways. Thanks for the assist. Really helped me. Maybe a bit hard for a 15 year old ;).

Comment: @SwastikBhattacharyya you're welcome! Glad to help :)

Comment: One more thing. I have some specific methods in my player class like `SetSkills`, `SetAge` and more and I have to do these methods each and every time for every player before starting the game. I think that this will impact the performance heavily and most importantly, I don't know how to do this :(. Any idea how to achieve it? Do I have to write a new question in StackOverflow to get the required answer?

Comment: see my update ... you should use a proper contructor instead of a lot of setter methods.

Comment: That means that I should write all the required functions on this void by using a constructor. I am updating my question to show you my entire 'Character' class. You will get the idea of the functions that are required. The functions are written in the bottom of the file.

Comment: Can you provide any answer for this @derHugo. No problem if you can't. You have helped me a lot already :)

Comment: Oh!!! Ok, now I understood what you meant by your update. No need to provide the answer, I got what you want to say. Thanks again. My bad.

Comment: Ok I can create a constructor but how can I create a Character using this Constructor.

Comment: Take the example of the string.format function inside the constructor. Let us say that I just create a ScriptableObject in Unity and then type the ```firstName```, ```lastName``` and ```middleName``` in the Inspector. Then, is there any chance that it will do that ```fullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, middleName, lastName);``` method when I click the Play Button. It will just make my life easier

Comment: Oh I didn't know `Character` was a `ScriptableObject` type ... Does it have to be?

Comment: you can't have a constructor for ScriptableObjects ... why does it have to be a ScriptableObject though? If you drag and drop those in the Inspector e.g. then why even bother with the `AddPlayer` method?

Comment: I had created another question in StackOverflow and @Shachash game me an answer and what he did is just created a ```void``` and copied everything from the ```Constructor```. But what I want to achieve (if possible which I think is not), is when I type the ```firstName```, ```middleName``` and ```lastName``` in the Inspector when creating an object, then Unity will automatically initalize the ```fullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, middleName, lastName);``` method.

Comment: @Shachash also created another class which creates a Character asset, through ```Character asset = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Character>();``` method, I guess this is the technique to go for?