# Create a Scriptable Object Instance through a Constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Character Scriptable Object and I have several methods in it. Like GetDate,GetAge (which I am not showing here). I have created a Constructor there, but I don't know how to create an instance of that ScriptableObject through the Constructor. That's what I want to do.

I have tried to just type the values in the inspector but that did not run the methods in the Constructor.

Character.cs

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
[Serializable]
public class Character : Scriptable Object
{
    // Attributes
    public string firstName;
    public string middleName;
    public string lastName;
    public string fullName;
    public bool isMale;

    // Constructor
    public Character(string _firstName, string _middleName, string _lastName, bool _isMale)
    {

        firstName = _firstName;
        middleName = _middleName;
        lastName = _lastName;

        // All The Functions 
        fullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, middleName, 
        lastName);

        isMale = _isMale;

        // and all the other functions like date calculator.
    }
}
```

I want to create an instance of this Scriptable Object through this Construction. Something like

```
Character char("x", "y", "z", true);
```

or when I type the required fields in the Unity Inspector, then it will run all the methods like that full name `string.format`.

Comment: Take the example of the ```string.format``` function inside the constructor. Let us say that I just create a ScriptableObject in Unity and then type the ```firstName```, ```lastName``` and ```middleName``` in the Inspector. Then, is there any chance that it will do that ```fullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, middleName, lastName);``` method when I click the Play Button. It will just make my life easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not like that. It is still unclear why you have to use `ScriptableObject`s
instead of having a simple class ([we came from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55519941/7111561)) where you would simply configure those Characters e.g. in the Inspector or use eg.

```
new Character("abc", "xyz", "kfk", true);
```

---

You could however have some kind of factory method like e.g.

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
[Serializable]
public class Character : Scriptable Object
{
    // Attributes
    public string firstName;
    public string middleName;
    public string lastName;
    public string fullName;
    public bool isMale;

    // Constructor
    private void Init(string _firstName, string _middleName, string _lastName, bool _isMale)
    {
        firstName = _firstName;
        middleName = _middleName;
        lastName = _lastName;

        // All The Functions 
        fullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, middleName, lastName);

        isMale = _isMale;

        // and all the other functions like date calculator.
    }

    public static Character CreateCharacter(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, bool isMale)
    {
        var character = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Character>();

        character.Init(firstName, middleName, lastName, isMale);
        return character;
    }
}
```

or alternatively do it e.g. in

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    fullName = $"{firstName} {middleName} {lastName}";
}
```

so it is there when the game starts.

---

If you really want to have it **while** typing those names in the Inspector you won't come around using a [Custom Inspector](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector) by implementing [`Editor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html)

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    using UnityEditor;
#endif

    public class Character : Scriptable Object
    {
        ...
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR

    [CustomEditor(typeof(Character))]
    public class CharacterEditor : Editor
    {
        private SerializedProperty firstName;
        private SerializedProperty middleName;
        private SerializedProperty lastName;
        private SerializedProperty fullName;

        // called once when the Object of this type gains focus and is shown in the Inspector
        private void OnEnable()
        {
            firstName = serializedObject.FindProperty("firstName");
            middleName= serializedObject.FindProperty("middleName");
            lastName= serializedObject.FindProperty("lastName");
            fullName= serializedObject.FindProperty("fullName");
        }

        // kind of like the Update method of the Inspector
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            // draw the default inspector
            base.OnInspectorGUI();

            serializedObject.Update();

            fullName.stringValue = $"{firstName.stringValue} {middleName.stringValue} {lastName.stringValue}";

            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }

#endif
```

alternatively to using `#if UNITY_EDITOR` you can ofcourse have the `CharacterEditor` in a complete separate script and put that one in a folder named `Editor`. In both cases the according code is stripped of in a build.

---

[image]

Comment: I think I will have to put this file in the Editor folder

Comment: Alright, trying the ```#if UNITY_EDITOR```. Just one question. What is the meaning of that ```OnEnable()```

Comment: of which? [ScriptableObject.OnEnable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.OnEnable.html) or in the [Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html)?

Comment: Do I have to put both the classes in the same file and then copy it to the Editor Folder? Since if I put the two classes in different folders then when I create an instance, it is giving me an error of ```Object Reference not Set to An Instance of An Object``` from the CharacterEditor.cs file in the Editor Folder.

Comment: nope! if you want to use the Editor folder than only the `CharacterEditor` has to be in it. you can have it in a completely separated file

Comment: Its however Giving an Error from ```fullName.stringValue = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName.stringValue, middleName.stringValue, lastName.stringValue);```. Saying ```Object Reference not Set to An Instance of An Object```

Comment: did you maybe rename the string variables? They have to match the ones in the Editor script in `FindProperty`. As you can see in the gif it is working for me ...

Comment: Oh, yeah, its a different game, but don't worry I managed to fix it. Thanks @derHugo I think that you have helped me twice now! You really are a awesome!

Comment: I have another ScriptableObject called 'Dynasty' and in there is a string called ```dynastyName```, that will be the last name of the character. Can I do that somehow? In my Character class there is a field called ```dynasty Dynasty``` which appears in the Inspector (Which I have to attach a Dynasty Object of course). Can the ```CharacterEditor.cs``` somehow get that ```dynastyName``` string instead of ```lastName```.

Comment: sicne those are two completely different Assets ... how are they connected?

Comment: No, there are two scriptable objects, 'Character' and 'Dynasty'. In Character, there is a ```public Dynasty dynasty```. I did that so that whenever I type full name it will be: ```firstName + " " + middleName + " " + dynasty.dynastyName;```. That's what I want to do. Shall I create a new question about this? Will that help?

Comment: I am creating a new question, I think that will help to understand because I cannot write the whole thing in a comment.

Comment: oh I see ... you could do it in the editor but using `SerializedProperty dynasty;` than in `OnEnable` add `dynasty = serializedObject.FindProperty(dynasty)` and than replace `lastName.stringValue` by `((Dynasty)dynasty.objectReferenceValue).dynastyName`. Anyway it will through a lot of errors while the object is empty ;)

Comment: It did work! Thanks a lot. However this only helps with strings. Can I add methods here like converting a string into a date through this. Like in the ```Character.cs``` I add a string called date. Then the ```CharacterEditor.cs``` would convert it to a DateTime Object. Is it possible, or we can only edit Strings through this. Basically, what I want to say is, all the inputs will be done in the inspector and the ```CharacterEditor.cs``` would process everything.

Comment: you can use it on any type but note that `DateTime` is not serializable by the Inspector. You would need to convert twice: current DateTime to string, edit this string in an Inspector field, convert new string back to DateTime. But this really getting out of scope now ;)

Comment: Really it is, but if I have to create like 1000 characters, would this make it easier for me, or do you suggest to not follow this method since it is really getting repetitive. But on a long run I think it is quite useful, especially if I create an asset and publish in Unity Store ;)

Comment: It is my ambition actually to become a Game Developer and I am only 15 now. I only code for fun and also for practice, that is why I love Coding "Out Of Scope" things, especially Editor Utilities, which makes life easier for everyone. Like that opinion system in which you helped me, that can save a lot of people's time (I think I am the only one with that script ;)). That is why I just love creating things, it's so fun for me. Anyway, what do you suggest on this problem?

Comment: This is greate and you should go on with it if you like it! What I ment is: It is getting out of the scope for your question here ;)

Comment: OK, I can't do that date, throwing lot of errors and it would take an eternity to write it. Can you show me the code (No problems if you can't :)).

Comment: Alright. I did it! Took a lot of time to figure out but still did it at the end. Anyway, thanks again to the power infinite ;).

Comment: This answer was exactly what I needed to humble me back into my senses. I was doing the whole constructor this, constructor that and overall just complicating my self into oblivion

Comment: Would it be much different if the instantiation method CreateCharacter is implemented outside of the scriptable object?

Comment: @Alex not at all, no. `CreateInstance` is a `public static` of `ScriptableObject` itself and can be called from anywhere. However, if you should happen to have any **`private`** fields/properties/methods you want to be able to set from the factory method, then it has to live within the type so you have access to those ;) (Note that this still doesn't create any assets from those instances so using ScriptableObject for this is quite questionable as mentioned above)

Comment: So if I have for example units in a game, is it more optimal to 1) create a gameobject (3d model) of a unit and attach a monoscript to it encapsulating its functionality and instantiate the gameobject as necessary, or 2) keep a scriptable object called Unit, where a 3d model is one of the variables; which is instantiated as part of the logic of the scriptable object?

Comment: @Alex completely depends on your use case ... ScriptableObject is mainly meant to be a reusable asset. They main use-case is for example you have a couple of equal behaviors - however the settings for those are stored in SOs so you can simply switch to another setting profile. In your case it sounds like the data is strong coupled to a specific GameObject instance so I would rather go with according component

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a new ScriptableObject Instance using a constructor (much like a monobehaviour). 
so you need to use Unity API methods

I have added a working sample

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[CreateAssetMenu]
[Serializable]
public class Character : ScriptableObject
{
// Attributes
public string firstName;
public string middleName;
public string lastName;
public string fullName;
public bool isMale;

// Constructor
public Character(string _firstName, string _middleName, string _lastName, bool _isMale)
{

    firstName = _firstName;
    middleName = _middleName;
    lastName = _lastName;

    // All The Functions 
    fullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, middleName,
    lastName);

    isMale = _isMale;

    // and all the other functions like date calculator.
}

public void Initialize(string _firstName, string _middleName, string _lastName, bool _isMale)
{
    firstName = _firstName;
    middleName = _middleName;
    lastName = _lastName;

    // All The Functions 
    fullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, middleName,
    lastName);

    isMale = _isMale;
}
```

}

and here is the class that creates the Character

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class Tester : MonoBehaviour
{
int characterCounter = 0;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Character c = CreateMyAsset();
        c.Initialize("a", "b", "c", true);
    }
}

public Character CreateMyAsset()
{
    Character asset = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Character>();

    string assetName = "Assets/c" + characterCounter + ".asset";
    characterCounter++;

    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(asset, assetName);
    AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();

    EditorUtility.FocusProjectWindow();

    Selection.activeObject = asset;
    return asset;
}


}
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer (I think this is the perfect one) but is there any way that the ```CreateMyAsset()``` could be done in the inspector?

Comment: Absolutly. You can write it inside an editor script. 
It's a bit of a big subject but I would start with Unity's tutorials on editor scripting